# How to build a user interface close to the iBooks one?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to build an iPad application that has a user interface close to the one that has been used for iBooks, or the one that Apple uses for the [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) and iPad operating systems, so is there any component in [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) that makes it easy for me?

In fact, I thought about the `UIImagPickerController`, but I'm sure yet.

Answer (score 2):

iBooks appears to be just a `UITableView` with a set of custom `UITableViewCells` that are drawn like the shelves. There is presumably a custom class which represents the books.

Apart from the level of drawing required, and the horizontal element, there is nothing 'special' in the way it is done.